# Windows 8.1 on bootcamp not hibernating

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro, windows, hibernate

I am running windows 8.1 on macbook pro retina.

When i trying to hibernate it is giving me an error `A device attached to the system is not functioning.(31)`

[image: A device attached to the system is not functioning.(31)]

Any thoughts what it could be related to?

BTW do not have any devices plugged to any port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after exploring and gooogling more about the issue I find out that it is some kind of driver failure issue.

I used [Driver Verifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drJMY.jpg) to check for driver failure
by running the command command `virifier /standard /all` - it will verify all the drivers in the system on startup and requires restart.

After restart I've got the blue screen of death saying that I've got `IRQ_LESS_OR_EQUAL` error and after that my Windows won't to boot at all...
BTW, the great article about `IRQ_LESS_OR_EQUAL` is [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1653275/fix-irql-equal-error-windows.html)

[image]

After a few failures windows give me an recovery options. So I chosen `command promt` to edit `virifier` options.

I was trying to switch `virifier /bootmodes`([Verifier Command Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to `disableafterfail` and to `oneboot` but none of them worked, I've got same `blue screen of death` saying about `IRQ_LESS_OR_EQUAL` error each time.

A have a [few options](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1653275/fix-irql-equal-error-windows.html) to try but I decided to use `system restore` first. So it worked.

After I boot the Windows I find out that `hibernation` is `working now`! but `touchpad double-pinch click` is stopped working for some reason. So I did try to install `BootCampDriversFolder\Drivers\Apple\AppleMultiTouchTrackPadInstaller64.exe` but it won't help. So I did run bootcamp drivers `setup.exe` and choose `repair option` from there. It reinstall the drivers and after restart all working so far, including `hibernation`!

Hope it will help any one else experiencing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any device plugged into a Thunderbolt port on the computer while in Bootcamp Windows will not be able to sleep or I presume manfully hibernate.

An article from MacWindows.com explains why:
http://www.macwindows.com/Thunderbolt-Limitations-of-Mac-running-Windows-and-getting-around-them.html

Comment: No devices plugged at all